# Как мне заполнить массив?

Tags: c++

Как мне заполнить массив вводом с клавиатуры через цикл, чтобы при присваивании элементам массива значений и при нажатии Enter курсор не перебегал на следующую строку? Мне нужно, чтобы он переходил на новую строку только когда заполнились все элементы этой строки. Надеюсь я понятно изложил проблему. Вот часть кода.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            cin >> ar[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Перемещение курсора по окне консоли зависит от ОС в общем случае, поэтому стоит упомянуть её в вопросе. Кроссплатформенно задачу, я думаю, можно решить с помощью ncurses. Или отказаться от нажатия Enter пока не ввели всю строку. А элементы в строке вводить через пробел.

Answer (score 0):

Пример заполнения:

```
const int n = 5; // Задавайте любые значения
const int m = 5; // Задавайте любые значения
int a[n][m];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        std::cin >> a[i][j];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Про курсор добавить не могу, ибо это зависит от компилятора и в целом ОС.

Answer (score -2):

```
int a[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
```

примерно так, только под многомерный массив переделать. пишешь элементы одной строки через пробел